# Border doesn't display in CSS, why?

Tags: html, css, input, border

I tried to add a border to the input but the border doesn't display. I don't know what the problem could be. Does anyone see something that I don't?

HTML:

```
<div class="word">
  <div class="search">
    <span class="text">Search</span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter word to search">
       <button><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.word .search input{
   position: absolute;
   height: 42px;
   width: calc(100% - 50px);
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 0 13px;
   border: 1px solid #e6e6e6 !important;
   outline: none;
   border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
   transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just remove the opacity or make it 1

```
<div class="word">
  <div class="search">
    <span class="text">Search</span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter word to search">
       <button><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.word .search input{
   position: absolute;
   height: 42px;
   width: calc(100% - 50px);
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 0 13px;
   border: 1px solid #e6e6e6 !important;
   outline: none;
   border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
   /*opacity: 0;*/
   pointer-events: none;
   transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
</style>
```

Comment: A need the opacity. If I remove I get a white background that I can remove with background-color: transparent but if I do the search bar doesn't work.
In the beginning this code worked with opacity and border was displayed. After it lost the border-color when I changed the color which is none sense.

Comment: @SarahRaven it's simply impossible to make the border works with opacity.

Comment: @SarahRaven you can remove the opacity and add a ```background: transparent;``` it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand precisely what you are trying to do but as stated in previous answers if you set the opacity to 0 the entire input including the border will be transparent/not visible. The search bar doesn't seem to do much in the code you provided as the `pointer-events: none;` results in the search bar being impossible to select.

So if you want a search bar with a border but with a transparent background, and it being clickable I would suggest the following:

```css
.word{
  background: lightgrey;
}

.search input{
   border: 2px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
   background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="word">
  <div class="search">
    <span class="text">Search</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter word to search">
    <button><i class="fas fa-search"></i>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```